# Cannot call method 'seekTo' when using jquery tools scrollable

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-tools, scrollable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scrollablein").scrollable({items:1});
    var api = $(".scrollablein").data("scrollablein");
    api.seekTo(1); 
})
```

jquery 1.7.1
jquery tools 1.2.5

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'seekTo' of undefined'

I tried to use another jquery(1.8.3,1.9.1,1.10.1) - didnt help.

Comment: Please add a link to _jQuery tools scrollable_, it will help people to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should type 'data("scrollable")' not name of the class. Works now

Answer (score 0):

.scrollable needs a library that you havent imported just including jquery wouldnt work you need to include the respective .scrollable library and jquery

if you have tried this resource for scroll

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/

it is using jquery tools lib which is

http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js